# Blazor MAUI app crashes on login page in Phone Device on TestFlight, but in the iPhone emulator it works

Tags: blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I have an application on Blazor Maui, version 7.0, it works fine on Android and Iphone emulators, it works fine on an Android device, but on an Iphone device it crashes after entering username and password in the Login page.

The error message that is generated when it crashes does not say what the problem is, please help me identify the error.

this is the crashlog.

Incident Identifier: 812F0B36-D84E-4116-BC13-8BF9D5DC0AC1
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             StrommarMember.Mobile7 [761]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/60FBAE69-7982-4501-AB67-BB6819EC8990/StrommarMember.Mobile7.app/StrommarMember.Mobile7
Identifier:          com.strommar.strommarbase.test
Version:             1.0 (16)
AppStoreTools:       14C17
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,8:16
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.strommar.strommarbase.test [505]

Date/Time:           2022-12-05 22:33:15.0430 -0400
Launch Time:         2022-12-05 22:32:49.3731 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.1.1 (20B101)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    5.01.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000016fa1bfb0
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x000000016fa1bfb0
VM Region Info: 0x16fa1bfb0 is in 0x16fa18000-0x16fa1c000;  bytes after start: 16304  bytes before end: 79
REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
MALLOC_TINY              155b00000-155c00000 [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV
GAP OF 0x19e18000 BYTES
--->  STACK GUARD              16fa18000-16fa1c000 [   16K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  ... for thread 0
Stack                    16fa1c000-16fb18000 [ 1008K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  thread 0
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [761]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Comment: How can we possibly help?  You haven't posted any code.  You haven't told us what "error message" you get.  You haven't posted any logs.  Have you attempted to debug it directly on the device?  Or installed any crash reporting tools?

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks.
If we have performed a direct Debug on the iPhone device and it does not crash, only when it is published through testFlight does the error occur.

What crash reporting tools can I use?

Comment: appcenter.ms, raygun.io, etc